# TypeError: Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined on using ng-submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I referred [Angular JS Form validation inside tabset give error : TypeError: Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647934/angular-js-form-validation-inside-tabset-give-error-typeerror-cannot-read-pro) but its not exactly what am looking for.

I have this html code,

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" required>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!userForm.$valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And my js is something like,

```
$scope.submitForm = function () {

    // check to make sure the form is completely valid
    if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
        alert('its working');
    }
};
```

I get this error. Is there a way to resolve this when am using `ng-submit`.

Comment: Why does your `ng-submit` have `submit()` when the function's name is `submitForm()`?

Comment: I have just put a part of the code.

Comment: Please give us code that actually represents what you have. Not internally inconsistent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try the code below:

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {

    // check to make sure the form is completely valid
    if (userForm.$valid) {
        alert('its working');
    }

};
```

I removed `$scope` from `$scope.userForm.$valid`, because userForm is not a property of `$scope`.

You could check the official AngularJS docs, [especially this part](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state), where you can see how they bind to the form.

Comment: This removes the error but submit was enabled. Should i add name attribute in the input tag?

Comment: That's because your `<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" required>` is missing a name. This way, validation will not work on the form. Add a `name="username"` tag and validation will work.

Comment: This applies for select tag also?

Comment: Yes, everything you want validation for needs a name-tag and an ng-model.